# UIActionView arrow position iPad

Tags: objective-c, uiactionsheet

I trying to create a drop down menu and I'm experimenting with an UIActionSheet. Is there a way to change the position of the arrow when the action sheet is displayed?

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                              initWithTitle:nil
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                              destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

[actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Mr"];
[actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Mrs"];
[actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Miss"];

[actionSheet showFromRect:[sender frame] inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **NO**.

For that functionality you will need to create your own alternative to the UIActionSheet.